# What would happen to the Moon if Earth was annhilated?

Tags: space, far-future

Sometime in the far future, the Earth gets destroyed. Before the Earth is destroyed, humans formed a small colony on the Moon which is capable of self-sustaining itself for the next decade or so. What would be the most logical, physics-obeying situation that would happen to the civilisation on the Moon?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding! I hope that you will find your experience on this site both interesting and useful. You may want to take the [tour] and read the [help] in order to become better acquainted with the rules and expectations of this site. (1) The title asks what would happend to the Moon, whereas the text of the question asks what would happen to the *civilization* on the Moon. Very different questions. (2) What would happen to the Moon depends on *how* the Earth gets destroyed, and the question does not say. It does not even say what it means by Earth getting destroyed.

Comment: Mainly I think we need to know what you mean by "destroyed". A nuclear holocaust is a lot different than the earth being vaporized by aliens or impacted by a 500 mile wide asteroid moving at half the speed of light.

Comment: One would think that, if Earth were randomly vaporized, that the Moon would simply drift off into the Sun's orbit. I find it unlikely that humans will survive as they would require considerable technology to survive and it seems unlikely that they'll have the industrial base to support the life support equipment necessary; e.g., performing maintenance, etc.

Comment: @dreamforge is right. The Moon's orbital velocity is about three orders of magnitude shy of being able to escape the Sun, and that's presuming that it's flung in the correct direction. The Moon would become a particularly large asteroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It depends on how the earth is destroyed

Consider three scenarios.

1. The surface of the earth is destroyed. Nanites, nuclear bombs, plagues, something kills everything on the surface of the earth. The moon and the earth will just keep orbiting the sun, and it doesn't care what happened to humans.
2. The earth is exploded equally in all directions. The [kinetic energy of the moon is about 10000 times smaller than the binding energy of the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)) so the moon is probably massively damaged and de-orbited.
3. The earth is de-orbited and flung into the sun. The earth has even more kinetic energy than binding energy, so this is also catastrophic for the moon.

As such, the only safe destruction is 1. The earth's surface is damaged and all Earthbound humanity destroyed, but it remains a big rock that's going around the sun. If you are fine with everyone on the moon dying, 2 or 3 is fine.

Comment: An interesting flavour of 1 is if some kind of experiment gone wrong or magic space weapon turns the Earth into a black hole. There'd just be a tiny, weird distortion in the sky if you knew where to look, though time and time again it'd pass in front of the Sun, which I imagine would be a noteworthy sight.

Comment: They asked for logical and physics obeying, so I didn't suggest anything that needed magical space weapons.

Comment: The Moon is not mechanically attached to the Earth by a rigid rod; It's the Earth's gravity that keeps it in orbit. As such, the Moon will almost certainly remain in a stable  solar orbit if you deorbit the Earth, unless your deceleration of Earth to the deorbiting is gentle enough to drag the moon along instead of letting it escape, or the Earth passes close enough to tear it to shreds,  or smacks into it.

Comment: Building on #2: if the mass of the Earth is pushed away from the center (I remember the discussions of "spherical horses" in my physics classes), then the moon will either be sucked into the expanding mass of the Earth (the same mass is there, but it's expansion means it's getting closer to the moon). Or, if it moves fast enough, it pushes the moon away, but eventually absorbs it. There's a very small chance of a *Space: 1999* kind of moon-spinning-off-into-space scenario, but that seems the least likely event. I can't find a way of saving the lunar occupants in case #2.

Comment: IN # 2, the debris  of Earth would Eventually expand into a radius equal to the distance of the Moon and keep on expanding past the moon and thus the surface of the Moon would be scoured by the expanding debris field and the relative orbital velocity of the Moon.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Let's debate... I think some fun will come of it. Is the mass and inertia of the moon so great that the expanding mass of the planet in its direction couldn't move it? If the expansion is slow, the Moon falls into the expanding mass of the Earth, cutting an inward-spiraling swath with increasing heat due to friction until it encounters the core material and kinda liquefies.  A fast enough expansion would scour the moon before friction (or the core material) burns it to a crisp. But could there be an expansion velocity that let's the moon escape with a buried base intact? ...

Comment: @M.A.Golding Or is it impossible for the mass of the Earth to expand at a slow enough velocity that would both allow for the expansion of the Earth and the (\*ahem\*) *safe* expulsion of the Moon? I guess in a way I'm asking, must the Earth's mass expand from the center at 11 km/s to avoid being drawn back down by the Earth's own gravity? If yes, is 11 km/s too slow or too fast to permit the Moon to escape as described? Now I'm really interested.... Is there enough distance between Earth and Moon at 11 km/s to avoid the moon being completely pulverized?

Comment: There are certainly ways to move the earth and safely decouple the moon into a solar orbit, but op said the Earth was destroyed, and that humanity just made a barely functional moon colony, so it doesn't sound like there was a gentle and careful process, and the sheer energy needed to move the earth is likely to be destructive to the moon colony.